# How do I apply (and correctly scale) textures on voxel objects?

Tags: texturing

I've applied a texture to a normal object, but when I try and apply it to a voxel object it doesn't want to work. How do I fix this? [image: Example]

Comment: You're not using a *Texture Coordinate* node here, and I'm not sure what the best results would be on this voxel object anyway.  Try it out by connecting the various outputs to the vector input of the *Image Texture* node.

Comment: How this should look like? Each voxel should look like the cube?